# Abort AWT application

Tags: java, swing, awt, event-dispatch-thread, thread-abort

I have an AWT application made by external company (I can't change it) and they call long time processes (calls to database) via event dispatch thread ... it means, when the application is waiting for results from database, the whole application doesn't respond to any user inputs (clicking exit button etc.)

Is there any way how programatically kill this application ... means for example wrap the application in other window, which is not connected with stuck event dispatch thread? Or somehow abort EDT? Or any other possibilities?

Comment: seriously? AWT? How long has your company been using this software? I would assume long enough to have figured out how to solve any issues by now?

Comment: Well, it's Swing ... but as I know, it's build on AWT and especially event handling has the same logic as AWT. Right? It is Oracle Forms ... we have been using it for many years, but it was applet in web browser. Now, when browsers don't support applets, Oracle came with stand alone application for launching Oracle Forms ... and this launcher has this problem ... in the past, when you load applets into web browser, also the applet get stuck by long running transaction ... but it was possible to close the whole browser. Now, there is no such possibility

Comment: you can always terminate the java process

Comment: *"Or any other possibilities?"* Ctrl+Alt+Del. (On Windows, at least, will provide access to the Task Manager - then .. join the dots.) But I'd go further than the first comment of @Stultuske - the company is using (apparently) unsupported code for which they don't have the source. They should bite the bullet and code the app. themselves. Anything less is madness.

Comment: @AndrewThompson indeed. trying to maintain the functionality of a Swng/AWT application while you can't alter the code .... pure madness ..

Comment: Thtat's nice ... but it is official approach how to open Oracle Forms (https://forms-demo.com/forms/html/fsal.htm), we have many applications build in this technology ...